# Unable to call and execute a function with PDO statements and a global variable

Tags: php, function, pdo, global-variables

I have a simple code with select and insert PDO statements..
In this code im inserting data on the basis of $p_id which is a global variable. I have executed the code without using function. But now having function in my code it doesnt work. Here is the code -

```
<?php

    include "connection.php";
    $p_id;

    if (!empty($_POST['prod_sub']))
    {   
         $sth = $dbo->prepare("SELECT production_ID FROM le_planning.log_production ORDER BY production_ID DESC LIMIT 1");
         $sth->execute();
         $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $count = $sth->rowCount();
         if($count > 0)
         {
              foreach($result as $arr)
              {
              $p_id = $arr['production_ID'];
              $p_id = $p_id+1;
              }
              prodExec();
         }
         else // FIRST TIME INPUT
         {
              $p_id = 1;
              prodExec();
         }

     function prodExec()
     {  
         global $p_id;    // GLOBAL
         $q = "INSERT INTO le_planning.transactions (Type, Type_ID) VALUES ('Production', $p_id)";
         $stmt = $dbo->prepare($q);
         if($stmt->execute())
         {echo "";}
         else{echo "Error!";}

         $sth1 = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM le_planning.temp_prod");
         $sth1->execute();
         $result1 = $sth1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $count1 = $sth1->rowCount();
         if($count1 > 0)
         {
              foreach($result1 as $item)
              {
              $Qty = $item['Qty'];
              $group_ID = $item['group_ID'];
              $component = $item['component'];
              $Component_ID = $item['Component_ID'];
              $stock_ID = $item['stock_ID'];

              $q1 = "INSERT INTO le_planning.log_production (production_ID, Transaction_ID, datetime, stock_ID, component, Component_ID, Qty) SELECT $p_id, MAX(Transaction_ID), now(), $stock_ID, '$component', '$Component_ID', $Qty FROM le_planning.transactions";
              $stmt1 = $dbo->prepare($q1);
              if($stmt1->execute())
              echo "";
              else{echo "Error!";}
              }
         }
     }
 }
?>
```

**WHAT I TRIED -**
this is the same logic but without the PDO statements and works like a charm.

```
<?php
$p_id;
$count = 0;
if($count > 0)
{
  $p_id=1;
  prodExec();  // gives output 1 when $count = 1
}
else
{
  $p_id=2;
  prodExec();  // gives output 2 when $count = 0
}   
function prodExec()
{
  global $p_id; 
  echo $p_id;
}
?>
```

Can anybody help me spot my mistake in here? Thanks.

Comment: [**GLOBALS are bad**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

Comment: @davidstrachan yes they are ! But there must be an alternative ! Functions are used frequently. I never thought about something this bad occurring in PHP !

Comment: You specify parameters when you define your function.ie `function prodExec($p_id)`

Comment: @davidstrachan i have tried each and every possible combination in functions be it using global keyword or $GLOBAL[] or passing params.. still theres no favourable outcome..